# Docker Running Python Error - [Error 2] No such file or directory

Tags: python, python-3.x, docker, dockerfile, docker-image

I am new to docker, I have prepared a dockerfile and built a basic docker image, however, I got this error when I run it. My dockerfile is below:

```
FROM python:3.8.6
MAINTAINER tester  tester
ADD . /code
WORKDIR /code
CMD ["python", "/app/Main.py"]
```

I used this command to build my docker image (I am in folder "test" to execute this command):

```
docker build -t my_test .
```

And then I use this command tp run my docker image:

```
docker run -it my_test
```

Then I have got this following error:

```
python: can't open file '/app/Main.py': [Errno 2] No such file or directory
```

I can confirm the folder "app" has got script "Main.py". What is the possible reason?

Thanks, [image]
[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you start a path with a `/` it corresponds to the root level.
Change the following line as follows:

```
CMD ["python", "/app/Main.py"]
```

to:

```
CMD ["python", "app/Main.py"]
```

OR

```
CMD ["python", "./app/Main.py"]
```

Comment: I have changed it to app/Main.py and it works, many thanks for the help!

Answer (score 1):

You're using a hard coded file path in the `CMD` which is ignoring your working directory, remove the prefixing slash

```
CMD ["python", "app/Main.py"]
```

Comment: I have changed my config file and it works, thanks for that